# Shuffling Text Loops using Animate.css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animate.css

Okay I am trying to make a page that cycles through terms using random entrances and exits (powered by [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)). I think my logic is pretty straightforward and in theory should work. However, when the page loads their is a long delay and then just the word "term 1" appears using a random entrance but does not exit.

Here is my code:

[html]

```
<div id="rotate"></div>
```

[js]

```
var terms = ["term 1", "term 2", "term 3", "term 4"];
var entrances = ["animated bounceInLeft", "animated fadeInLeft", "rotateInDownLeft", "rotateInUpLeft",
    "slideInLeft", "zoomInLeft", "rollIn"];
var exits = ["animated bounceOutRight", "animated fadeOutRight", "rotateOutDownRight", "rotateOutUpRight",
    "slideOutRight", "zoomOutRight", "rollOut"];
var count = 0;

    function rotateTerm() {
        if (terms[count] < terms.length) {
            wordGen(terms[count]);
        }
        else {
            count = 0;
            wordGen(terms[count])
        }
        count += 1;
        rotateTerm();
    }

    function wordGen(t) {
        $("#rotate").text(t).addClass(entrances[Math.floor((Math.random() * entrances.length))])
                // the following code waits for the animation from 
                // the entrance to end then performs the function()
                .one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', 
                 function () {
                    $("#rotate").text(t).addClass(exits[Math.floor((Math.random() * exits.length))])
                })
    }
window.onload = rotateTerm();
```

Any assistance on what I am doing wrong? Or a better approach? Or anything in general!

Comment: Your HTML code is invalid. Use a `<div>` instead.

Comment: Ooops. That changer tag is due to my css. But for this purpose I will change it to div.

Comment: Is it really supposed to change the content recursively?

Comment: Hmmm. I am not sure what you mean? Do you mean when I call rotateTerm() within rotateTerm()? That is just so I can get it to loop infinitely.

Comment: And that is the root of your problem. Everytime it loops, it will change everything. And since it is looping every nanosecond, you should expect weird behaviour. Basically: it is changing your text inside that div every single nanosecond. Remove that from there.

Comment: Hmmmm. So what is the proper (or best practice) when it comes to approaching this without having that function call itself?

Comment: Use a `setTimeout` or a `setInterval`.